# Is $[0,1]$ a 1-manifold?

Tags: manifolds, compact-manifolds

Is $[0,1]$ a 1-manifold?  I would say no because at either endpoint the open sets containing it aren't homeomorphic to a 1-ball in $\mathbb R^1$.

Comment: Now take the union of $\{(0,t)\in\mathbb{R}^2:\ 0\leq t<1\}$ and $\{(t,0)\in\mathbb{R}^2:\ 0\leq t<1\}$. Is it a manyfold?

Comment: That's a 1-manifold (without boundary), right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are correct. It is not a $1$-dimensional manifold, but it is a $1$-dimensional [manifold with boundary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifold#Manifold_with_boundary). Confusingly, a manifold with boundary is not a manifold.

Comment: Might it be worth mentioning that this is only a convention?  (There are some who seem to insist that the fact that the product of no numbers is a convention, not a fact.  I think they're entirely and demonstrably wrong, but the demonstration has never yet been written in just one place.  But these definitions about manifolds are conventions.)

Comment: @Michael: Of course whether a manifold with boundary is a manifold depends on your definition of manifold, and a definition is a kind of convention.  Did you mean more than this?  E.g., do you mean that some people have defined "manifold" so as to include "manifolds with boundary"?  (That is certainly true, and in informal usage it is common not to always make the distinction.)

Comment: I don't think definitions are always merely a matter of convention.  Some definitions make sense and some don't.  But nobody's codified the canons in this area the way they have with deductive logic.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: I suppose it does depend on your definition of manifold, but every source I have ever seen requires each point to have a neighbourhood homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$. In particular, using the definitions in the Wikipedia article I linked to, my final statement is correct.

Answer (score 3):

It is a $1$ manifold with boundary but not a $1$ manifold. The boundary points are homeomorphic to open sets in $\mathbb{H}^{1}=[0,\infty)$.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct, the open balls around $1$ and $0$ are not homeomorphic to $\mathbb R$.  It's one thing to see this intuitively, but to prove it note that any open ball $[0, a)$ contains a nonempty compact set $[0, b]$ ($b < a$) whose complement is path connected.  But the path connected open sets in $\mathbb R$ are intervals and the complement of an interval can never be nonempty and compact.

As the other answerers have noted, $[0, 1]$ is instead something called a manifold with boundary.

Answer (score 0):

I simplify Jim's answer. Since $[0, a)$ is open in $[0, 1]$ and it is connected, then $\phi([0, a))$ should be connected and open in $\def\R{\mathbb{R}}\R$. Thus it is a interval in $\R$, i.e., $\phi([0, a))=(c, f)$. Now, if we let $\phi(0)=e$. Then $\phi(0, a)=(c, e)\cup (e,f)$. But $(0, a)$ is connected, and $(c, e)\cup (e,f)$ is not connected.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! But it is a manifold WITH boundary, because you can have two coordinate patches from $[0,1)$ (which is open in the upper half space $\mathbb{H^1} = [0,\infty)$) to $[0,1]$ that satisfies the

1. $1$ to $1$ property
2. Being $C^r$
3. its inverse being continuous
4. $D\alpha \neq 0$

For example, you can let
$$\alpha_1(t) :[0,1) \rightarrow [0,1), \alpha_1(t) = t$$
$$\alpha_2(t) :[0,1) \rightarrow (0,1], \alpha_2(t) = 1-t$$

Combining these two patches, they cover all of $[0,1]$!