# Why a lemniscate is not an example of a 1-manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

**Context**.  My knowledge of geometry is pretty much zero.  I wanted to know what a [manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifold) is.  (Just what the word means --- at least for now.)  It seems a manifold is something that will locally feel like an Euclidean plane.  So far so good.  The Wikipedia article then gave examples of 1-manifolds such as a line and a circle, but then it said that a lemniscate is not a 1-manifold.  The question is --- why not?

**A wild guess**.  Looking at [similar questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/469867), I take the risk of saying that the problem is that a lemniscate crosses itself, so we could zoom in at a crossing point and the "x" from the crossing could never be "equivalent" ("homeomorphic" I guess) to an Euclidean line.  Why not?  Because the crossing point is never 1-dimensional --- it always needs two dimensions, otherwise it's not a crossing point.

Comment: If you take the $X$ as a topological space, this is not homeomorphic to an $I$ as a topological space.
Proof: if you remove the crossing point from the $X$ then you end up with 4 segments homeomorphic to $[0,1)$, on the other hand if you remove an interior point from the $I$, you end up with two such copies.

Comment: A distinction here needs to be made between the domain and image of a curve. The image of the curve is an immersion of a manifold (the line), but is not a manifold itself (since the image crosses itself at a single point so is not locally Euclidian). Anyhow, the tangent space at the origin has dimension $2$ so it can not be a $1$-manifold.

Comment: @Overflowian, I think I see what you're showing me --- you're showing me a technique of proving that two topological spaces are not the same.  If we remove a point from two homeomorphic spaces, the subtracted spaces should still be homeomorphic to each other.  (So, the $X$-space could not be homeomorphic to the $I$-space.)  (Thank you!  I was not thinking of anything like that at all.)

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen, thank you for the distinction and the tangent-space mention.  My next step here will be to study how to get the dimension of a tangent space, but I suppose this is easy --- the equation of the tangent line will not be a $1$-degree equation, so the dimension of such line is not $1$.  (In other words, I'm not sure how  to get the dimension of a tangent space.)  (I'm more than well-served here.  Thanks, everyone.)

Comment: Thank you, @JWTanner, for the ortography.

Comment: Although I admire your politeness, I feel like the above comments are intentionally being way too technical for the level at which you are asking your question. All that needs to be said is that the intuition behind your "wild guess" is correct.